# How do you remove Link backs on Theme settings page?

Tags: themes

How do we edit and remove link backs to theme Developers from theme settings page ? Some themes which we install on site has link backs .How do you edit them from multisites?

Does any body have Idea on removing these links?

I want to edit the Links Like "Mystique 2.4.2 by [digitalnature](http://digitalnature.ro/)" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea is to search theme files for text of the link and remove code that inserts it.

- Best case scenario it would be single line to remove.
- Worst case scenario - link would be added by highly obfuscated code and rigged to break theme if link is removed.

Since theme you referenced is in official theme repository it would be unlikely to have obfuscated code.